# How do I propagate a return value from a nested asynchronous function in javascript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, nested

I have a part of a code like

```
function outerFunction() {
  // adapter.getUpdate is asynchronous
  adapter.getUpdate(objectId,
    function (err, update) {
      if (err)
        return err; // I want to propagate this error message forward
      // do some work
    }
  );
}
```

where I want the error message to be available wherever outerFunction() is called.
Also, the `adapter.getUpdate()` method is asynchronous.

Comment: that's not possible, you'll need to use a callback for that

Answer (score 1):

use a callback and execute it whenever the error occurs:

```
/**
 * @param {Function} onerrorcb
 */
function outerFunction(onerrorcb) {
  // adapter.getUpdate is asynchronous
  adapter.getUpdate(objectId,
    function (err, update) {
      if (err) {
          onerrorcb(err) // execute
          return;
      }
      // do some work
    }
  );
}
```

and then you can use it like this:

```
outerFunction(function(err) {
    // handle error here
})
```

Comment: Hmm.. what is `onerrorcb`? If it is a function, what should be there in the definition?

Comment: as you can see in my answer, `onerrorcb` is a function that receives one parameter: `err` and is executed whenever the error occurs, it can be declared like this: `function(err){}`